# Graph theory: plex and clique

Tags: graph-theory

How do a 2-plex relates to a 2-clique? 
I think that being a 2-plex means that is also a 2-clique but i don't know how to prove it.
Thanks,

Comment: What is a 2-plex? A 2-simplex (i.e. triangle)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean [these definitions](http://faculty.ucr.edu/~hanneman/nettext/C11_Cliques.html) of a $k$-plex and $k$-clique...

...you should first be informed that these are not very standard, and basically no graph theorist uses this terminology (in particular, most people will take "$k$-clique" to mean "clique on $k$ vertices")...

...but yes, except in small cases. If we define a *$k$-plex* in a graph $G$ to be an $n$-vertex subgraph with minimum degree $n-k-1$ (with respect to the subgraph), and a *$k$-clique* to be a subgraph in which any two vertices are at distance at most $2$ (with respect to all of $G$), then any $2$-plex on at least $5$ vertices will be a $2$-clique.

If $v,w$ are any two vertices in a $2$-plex, then either $vw$ is an edge, or $v$ and $w$ each have at most one other vertex in the $k$-plex they're not adjacent to. If there are at least three other vertices in the $k$-plex, then one might not be adjacent to $v$, and another might not be adjacent to $w$, but the third is just right.

As a result, in a $2$-plex on at least $5$ vertices, any two vertices are at distance $1$ or $2$, and so the $2$-plex is a $2$-clique.

On the other hand, a $2$-plex on $3$ or fewer vertices might not have any edges, and a $2$-plex on $4$ vertices might just be a path of length $3$. Such subgraphs are not $2$-cliques on their own; they might become $2$-cliques by connections outside of the subgraph, but they also might not.

In general, the same argument shows that a $k$-plex on at least $2k+1$ vertices is always a $2$-clique. Moreover, since we don't use any edges outside the subgraph, it is not just a $2$-clique but (borrowing more of the weird terminology) a $2$-clan.

Comment: So it relates to a 2-club if the vertex is less then 5

Comment: I don't know what a 2-club is.

Comment: K-club is for any 2 vertex in a graph  G the is a chain that unite them with only vertex in G with the max of k edges

Comment: So it's the same thing as a $k$-clan?

Comment: Ok. We call it club. How do you find algebric 2k+1?

Comment: If there are $2k+1$ vertices, then even if two of them are $v$ and $w$, $k-1$ are not adjacent to $v$, and $k-1$ are not adjacent to $w$, that leaves one more vertex that is adjacent to both.

Comment: But my teacher said that any k-plex os k-clan

Comment: That seems like a bizarre claim to make about this set of definitions; double-check that your definition of $k$-plex agrees with mine, I guess? Any sufficiently large $k$-plex is a $2$-clan/$2$-club, but a $k$-plex on $2k$ or fewer vertices might not even be connected at all! A $2$-club is, of course, a $k$-club, but there doesn't seem to be any correspondence between $k$-plexes and $k$-clubs in particular.

Comment: So to be a plex it doenst need to be connected?

Comment: Not by the definition I'm seeing.

Comment: So 3 vertices isolated are a 2-plex and 2-club?

Comment: They are a 2-plex (every vertex is adjacent to all but two others) but not a 2-club (there is no path of any length between two different vertices).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But then the 2k +1 doenst work.

Comment: When $k=2$, $2k+1$ is $5$, not $3$.

Comment: Ok. One more question. If is a 2-club is a 2-clique. So whats the difference between a club and a clique?

Comment: A 2-clique takes into account connections via vertices outside the 2-clique as well. Take a complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$. Then either part of the bipartition is a 2-clique of size $n$ (between any two vertices, there is a path of length $2$ in $K_{n,n}$) but not a 2-club (as a subgraph, one part of the bipartition is an independent set, and has no edges at all - and therefore no paths of length $2$).

Comment: Ok understod. Thank you